# Dockerfile from Jenkins JDK 11 with Docker engine installed - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, jenkins, debian

Ive created a Dockerfile that is based off `jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11`

Im trying to install docker + docker compose so that jenkins will have access to this when i create my pipeline for CD/CI.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11 AS jenkins

WORKDIR /home/jenkins

RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /var/jenkins_home

USER root

# Install aws cli version 2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip curl vim bash sudo
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install

#Install docker cli command
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
      $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

##Install docker compose
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
RUN curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.2.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

RUN sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

The docker commands work well within the container but as soon as i start to build an image it displays this error:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

If i try to start the docker service with `service docker start` i get the following error:

`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘cpuset’: Read-only file system`

Im not sure how to solve this one.

TIA

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the exact same problem :)

Comment: @Mark Nope, i ended up using a EC2 instance on AWS and running Jekins + docker. I also use Jenkins to spin up more EC2 slaves for testing + building etc.

Comment: i am getting the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while trying to run docker inside the Jenkins container using ECS Fargate.

TLDR: Fargate doesn't support [privileged containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/fargate-security-considerations.html). So you need to switch to EC2 to be able to run docker.

I used the following setup:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
USER root

# Install Docker and Docker Compose
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \
                       ca-certificates \
                       curl \
                       gnupg-agent \
                       software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io && \
    curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# Install necessary plugins for Jenkins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins \
        docker-workflow \
        blueocean \
        pipeline-utility-steps \
        cloudbees-folder

# Setup Debian to use the legacy iptables instead of nftables
RUN  update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy && \
     update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy

# Expose ports for Jenkins
EXPOSE 8080
```

Container should be launched with the following command:

```
docker run --privileged -p 8080:8080 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home myjenkins
```

Before running any docker command use `service docker start` command to start docker.

Comment: Thank you. i just stuck with an ec2 instance that spawns EC2 slaves when needed. works well.

Answer (score 0):

container does not use an init system. The Docker service cannot be started because of this.